# HTML5 <audio> tags donesn't work on Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, html5-audio

I have this radio stream player code. It words perfectly on Chrome and iOS Safari,  but it won't work on Firefox and Internet Explorer 11.

It's a bit of my index.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("pause")) {
        image.src = "play.png";
       document.getElementById('sound1').pause();
    } else {
        image.src = "pause.png";
       document.getElementById('sound1').play();
    }
}
</script>
```

When you enter the page, the image is "play.png" by default. When you press on it it changes to "pause.png" and the music starts playing.

And here's this script in html:

```
<audio id="sound1" src="http://radiostation.com:8000/stream" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage();" src="play.png" style="position: absolute; top: 130px; left: 23px;">
```

The problem is only on playing the stream, the image changes on all browsers. Would be grateful for any any help. Thanks :)

Comment: `http://radiostation.com:8000/stream` - is clearly a dummy name, right - what would be helpful to know is the actual audio type that is being sent

Comment: Sorry, it's http://radijas.tau.lt:8000/stream and the format is .m3u file. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and Internet explorer do not support audio/aacp content, which is the format of that stream

For this stream you could use /stream2 which is audio/mpeg which is more widely supported amongst browsers

> NOTE - developer version of firefox DOES support audio/aacp - so things may change in about 6 to 12 weeks

Comment: hence why I said "**may** change" - I think firefox has fairly universal mp3 support these days (based on [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats))

Comment: Hi, it works on my computer on all browsers not, thanks for help. But I just got to work and tried it on the newest version of Chrome and Firefox and it won't work. The computer runs on Windows XP, may that could be the case?

Comment: What could I do for it to work? There are a lot of radio stations which web players work on Windows XP. A different audio format perhaps?

Comment: other web players use adobe flash as a fallback

Comment: I just got home. I'm thinking that it should stick with HTML5 player, but when someone visits with Windows XP I need to play audio with Flash player. Am I correct? If so, can you recommend me flash player which is easy to use in my case? I'm kind of lost at this point. Thanks for all your help by the way :)